# application flow in iphone program

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am making a application for the iphone and i am using window based application and i am doing this:

1. #importing all `UIViewController` class in the `appDelegate` class.
2. creating the object for accessing the variables and function and I am controlling all 
   action,event and controls from the `appDelegate` class.

I want to ask that is this right approach. I dont want to use view based application, I want to use `UIViewController` class just only controllers display.

If this is not a good approach for making the application tell me the good process for doing this.

Comment: You need to explain a bit more, what is your application going to do/look lik, etc. Anyway, it's not a good approach handling all events in the `appDelegate`-class, this should be done in each `UIViewController` instead. I suggest you try to go through a couple of tutorials before making this app.

Comment: ok, but what if i have 3 to 4 uiviewController class who i will transfer the variables and function between them, i can manage this thing through appDelegate easily. plz give me a good approach to make a iphone application.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at this:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/10/11/back-to-basics-an-introduction-to-view-controllers/

You should also read up on the iPhone-programming-basics, you will find a lot of nice tutorials and articles with a quick Google-search for "iPhone programming".

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a singleton that holds the data and methods you want to share and access it from any view controller you want.  Conceptually, it's not much different then what you are doing with the appDelegate class but it is better so that you don't clutter up the app delegate.

Comment: ok, in my application i have 4 uiviewController every class has 2 text feild, i have a xml which gives the data to these text fields, i am importing the xml class in all uiviewcontroller class to get the data. is it a right way.......?

Comment: If the XML class you are talking about is a singleton, then yes.  You will need to import the singleton class into every view controller that you want to access the data.  Just make sure it is a singleton and you are only instantiating it once.